# What is the metric of the $\mathscr{l}^\infty$ space?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

In one exercise, I have to prove that the space $\mathscr{l}^\infty$ (in $\mathbb{R}$) with respect to *sup-norm* is complete but I'm not conversant with this space. From this Wikipedia's [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-infinity), I understand that the metric needs not be explicitly defined for $\mathscr{l}^\infty$ and any valid metric could be used.

So, I've tried a metric defined as follows:

$$
d(x, y)=
\begin{cases}
1\text{ if }x\ne y,\\
0\text{ otherwise},
\end{cases}
$$

and see that the $\mathscr{l}^\infty$ is still complete with respect to *sup-norm* (even with respect to any other norm). This is because every Cauchy sequence in this metric space has to have a term, which is also a sequence, repeated forever after specific index.

However, by searching this site, I've found several questions about $\mathscr{l}^\infty$ space showing that the metric for this space is induced by the *(sup-)norm*.

Is that true the metric for the $\mathscr{l}^\infty$ space is always induced by the norm (*sup-norm* in this specific case)?

Comment: In standard notations this  space is always given the sup norm.

Comment: @geetha290krm how about the metric, it's what the question is about?

Comment: @TranKhanh if you have normed space, by default it's assumed that we use metric induced by norm, $d(x, y) = \|x - y\|$.

Comment: @mihaild, thanks!